# Local de conexão do usuário no MySQL ou MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, permissões

É recomendado eu alterar o local de conexão de um usuário a partir da tabela `mysql.user`?

Por exemplo, eu crio um usuário `'danilo'@'localhost'` mas depois quero que ele se conecte de qualquer maquina, tem outra forma de eu fazer isso sem fazer um `update` na tabela `mysql.user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os usuários funcionam de outra forma. Um usuário deve ser cadastrado de acordo com o local onde ele pode acessar. Ainda que seja a mesma pessoa quando ele acessa de um lugar ou de outro o privilégio deve ser, em tese, diferente. Então não é possível alterar essa informação do usuário, porque ela é parte fundamental dele. O correto é remover esse usuário e criar um novo com os mesmos privilégios, mas agora aceitando as máquinas que deseja direto no nome do usuário. Ele é como se fosse um e-mail, um `jose@gmail.com` é diferente do `jose@outlook.com`. Poderiam ter deixado isso isolado, mas não fizeram.

Existe a gambiarra de alterar na própria tabela mudando o dado na coluna. Ainda que funcione não é o adequado e não espere que funcione sempre.